# ArrayOutOfBounds exception when trying to parse Double to String

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I am struggling with an assignment where data from a text file must be stored into an ArrayList, this includes string values for a songs description, and double values for duration and rating values.

Sorry for the messiness, I am new to this site.

Here is the error that is displayed when I try to printSongs()

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at Song.printSongs(Song.java:181)
    at Song.Submenu(Song.java:106)
    at Song.mainChoice(Song.java:85)
    at Song.main(Song.java:208)**
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.lang.Iterable;


public class Song 
{


public int songID;
    public String title;
    public String artist;
    public double duration;
    public String genre;
    public double rating;
    public String album;
    public static Scanner keyboard;
    public static Scanner fileIn;
    public static int choice = 0;

  @Override
   public String toString() 

  {
                return ("ID: "+this.getSongID() + " " +
                        "Title: "+ this.getTitle() + " " +
                        "Artist: "+ this.getArtist() + " " +
                        "Album: "+ this.getAlbum() + " " +
                        "Duration: "+ this.getDuration() + " " +
                        "Genre: "+ this.getGenre() + " " +
                        "Rating: "+ this.getRating() + " ");




   }



public Song(int songID, String title, String artist, String album,
        double duration, String genre, double rating) 
{
    this.songID = songID;
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.album = album;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.rating = rating;









}




public static void displayAll() throws FileNotFoundException
{



}

public static void mainChoice()
{
    System.out.println("Make your selection:");
    System.out.println("-------------------");
    System.out.println("1. Songs");
    System.out.println("2. Playlists");
    System.out.println("3. Import/Rip CD");
    System.out.println("4. Save");
    System.out.println("5. Exit Program");
    System.out.println("-------------------");
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    choice = keyboard.nextInt();
    Submenu();      
}

public static void Submenu()
{
    System.out.println("-------------------");

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("     SONGS     ");
        System.out.println("1. Display Songs");
        System.out.println("2. Sort Songs");
        System.out.println("3. Rate Song");
        System.out.println("4. Set Genre");
        System.out.println("5. Exit Submenu");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        choice = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            printSongs();
        }

        if (choice == 2)
        {

        }

        if (choice == 3)
        {

        }

        if (choice == 4)
        {

        }

        if (choice == 5)
        {
            System.out.println("-------------------");
            mainChoice();
        }

    }

    if (choice == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("   PLAYLISTS     ");
        System.out.println("1. Display");
        System.out.println("2. Create Playlist");
        System.out.println("3. Add Song");
        System.out.println("4. Exit Submenu");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        choice = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1)
        {

        }

        if (choice == 2)
        {

        }

        if (choice == 3)
        {

        }

        if (choice == 4)
        {
            System.out.println("-------------------");
            mainChoice();
        }
    }


    }


public static void printSongs()
{
       ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>(); 



        try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream("songCollection.txt"), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                String[] arr = line.split(",");
                songs.add(new Song(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], Double.parseDouble(arr[4]), arr[5], Double.parseDouble(arr[6]) ));
            }


        } catch (IOException err) 
        {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }



        for (Iterator<Song> iterator = songs.iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();) 
        {
            System.out.println(songs); 
        }


}






public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
   mainChoice();



}






public String getAlbum() {
    return album;
}






public void setAlbum(String album) {
    this.album = album;
}






public double getRating() {
    return rating;
}






public void setDuration(int duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}




public void setRating(int rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}






public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}






public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}






public double getDuration() {
    return duration;
}






public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}






public void setArtist(String artist) {
    this.artist = artist;
}






public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}






public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}






public int getSongID() {
    return songID;
}






public void setSongID(int songID) {
    this.songID = songID;
}



}
```

Comment: Print out the value of `line` or `arr` before the error and I'm sure you'll see why you're getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` Exception.

Comment: Well, you obviously have at least one line in the file that doesn't have 7 elements separated by a comma. Check your input file.

Comment: Thanks, I see that it is because at line 12, there is a blank ratings value, this is meant to be blank, and another method will handle the user setting a new rating. How would I rectify this, and stop it from trying to store an empty value into an array?

Comment: Please post the contents of your input file, or at least the offending line.

Comment: No problem.
Here is the offending line:
12,Pineapple Head,Crowded House,Recurring Dream,3.5,Rock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated that the offending line in your input file is:

```
12,Pineapple Head,Crowded House,Recurring Dream,3.5,Rock
```

That line is missing the 7th element (rating). So, obviously, `String.split()` will return an array of 6 items instead of 7, and trying to access the 7th gives you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because, well, the array index is out of bounds.

When you are reading your input file, you must make sure your program reads the data according to the rules you've defined about how your input file should be formatted. You state that your input file can be missing rating data, but your program assumes that every line contains 7 elements, therefore your program is not following your rules and you can't be surprised when it breaks!

The easy solution is to check the length of the array that `line.split(",")` returns and handle the data accordingly. If there are 7 elements, then you have every field. If there are 6 elements, the rating is missing. If there is something besides 6 or 7, the input line is malformed -- it's up to you to determine how to handle that (crash, or ignore, or print an error, whatever you decide).

Also, by default, `String.split()` does not return trailing empty fields, this sounds like it's what you want for this assignment, but check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29 for more information on your other options here.

Comment: Is there any way to simply use continue; to skip to the next line, essentially ignoring the error? Or atleast to set it to 0.0 by default?

Comment: Yes; you'd make your program do exactly that -- Hint: IF there's only 6 elements, then use 0.0 for the rating. Translation: if (there are 6 elements) { use 0.0 for the rating }.

Comment: Listen to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlkVic-v2Go while you work, it may help. :P

Comment: Thank you it worked.
Now, if possible, I am trying to sort my songs Arraylist into alphabetical order in a seperate method called sortSongs() with the code - Collections.sort(songs);
This does not work however, saying that "songs cannot be resolved to a variable", does this mean I have to pass this ArrayList in via the initial arguments of the sortSongs() method (just like a constructor) or do I have to call it within the sortSongs() method, if so how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime `Exception` is thrown because of the code you have in `printSongs`, when you split the text line and initialize a new `Song` with the different splits.

You are either assuming a wrong format for your text, or your text itself is malformed somewhere.

In short, you are referencing an element of the dynamically created split `String` array, but that element does not exist.

```
String[] arr = line.split(",");
songs.add(new Song(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], 
                                    // that's your problem
Double.parseDouble(arr[4]), arr[5], Double.parseDouble(arr[6]) ));
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that it is because at line 12, there is a blank ratings value, this is meant to be blank, and another method will handle the user setting a new rating. How would I rectify this, and stop it from trying to store an empty value into an array?

Comment: @user2947257 sorry just seen your answer now (use "@" + [name] to make sure a person is notified). You should consider checking the length of your array in order to make sure you can initialize your `Song` class with all its parameters. Something along the lines of `if arr.length == 7` I guess. **Edit** oh wait... already answered by someone else :D

Comment: Thankyou very much nonetheless Mena! I managed to work out the arr.length if statement on my own, just needed a step in the right direction.

Comment: @user2947257 Cool! Best of luck with it then :)